# Coercion to LP of the absolute value of a fraction in constraint of minimization problem

Tags: statistics, optimization, linear-programming

Frandsen et al.'s 2023 paper "Judging Judge Fixed Effects" proposes a statistical test that they claim can be cast as a linear programming problem. However, they do not provide the details on how to do so, and in working it out myself, I have not quite been able to get all the way there. I know the solutions to problems like this can be highly dependent on the specific setting, and so will try to provide all relevant details.

The sample is made up of judges, indexed by $j$, who decide whether or not to treat individuals who, conditional on being treated, do or do not have a successful outcome. The data are thus each judge's treatment rate, $\hat{p}_j$, and average outcome $\hat{y}_j$, which each of course lie between 0 and 1.

The paper shows that, under a particular set of assumptions, at the population level, average outcomes must lie on a continuous monotonic function of treatment rates, and that the slope of said function is bounded by the minimum and maximum values of $y$. The proposed test considers whether the data support these assumptions holding, by coming up with candidate population values that satisfy the slope constraints while minimizing their discrepancies with the data. The problem can be stated as follows.

$$min_{\{\tilde{y}_j, \tilde{p}_j\}_j} max \{\hat{T}_j(\tilde{y}_j, \tilde{p}_j)\}^J_{j=1}$$
$$s.t. \left\{\left\{\left| \frac{\tilde{y}_j - \tilde{y}_{j'}}{\tilde{p}_j - \tilde{p}_{j'}} \right| \leq K \right\}^{J-1}_{j=1}\right\}^J_{j'=j+1}$$

$K$ is a constant in $(0, 1]$. $\hat{T}_j \equiv max\{|\hat{T}_{1j}|, |\hat{T}_{2j}|\}$ where $\hat{T}_{1j}$ and $\hat{T}_{2j}$ are linear functions of $\{\tilde{y}_j, \tilde{p}_j\}$.

I can very nearly make this linear by putting it in the following form.

$$min_{\{\hat{T},\{\tilde{y}_j, \tilde{p}_j\}_j\}} \hat{T}$$
$$s.t. \hat{T} \geq \{\hat{T}_{1j}\}^J_{j=1}$$
$$\hat{T} \geq \{-\hat{T}_{1j}\}^J_{j=1}$$
$$\hat{T} \geq \{\hat{T}_{2j}\}^J_{j=1}$$
$$\hat{T} \geq \{-\hat{T}_{2j}\}^J_{j=1}$$
$$\left\{\left\{\frac{\tilde{y}_j - \tilde{y}_{j'}}{\tilde{p}_j - \tilde{p}_{j'}} \leq K \right\}^{J-1}_{j=1}\right\}^J_{j'=j+1}$$
$$\left\{\left\{-\frac{\tilde{y}_j - \tilde{y}_{j'}}{\tilde{p}_j - \tilde{p}_{j'}} \leq K \right\}^{J-1}_{j=1}\right\}^J_{j'=j+1}$$

I've dealt with the max function, the absolute value in the definition of $\hat{T}_j$, and, seemingly, the absolute value in the constraint. It appears that I can simply rearrange the terms of the last two constraints to make them linear. However, this is not the case because I do not know the sign of $\tilde{p}_j - \tilde{p}_{j'}$, which matters because I may or may not need to flip the direction of the inequality.

I've been thinking about this issue for a while now, and just cannot figure out the final step. It's possible that my approach up to this point is not the way.

One thing I've been wondering about is whether I can order the judges such that $\tilde{p}_j - \tilde{p}_{j'}$ is always positive. However, I'm not certain that this is possible. I of course know $\hat{p}_j$ for all the judges, but, due to variation in $\hat{y}_j$, I do not think $\hat{p}_j > \hat{p}_{j'}$ implies $\tilde{p}_j > \tilde{p}_{j'}$.

What do you guys think? Is there a solution I'm missing? Are the authors wrong??

Comment: I don't have experience with LP or MILP, but am thinking that this should at least be doable via MILP.
Though the paper doesn't mention MILP if that's what they had in mind. So it's still very possible that it can be done with simple LP, and I'm just missing it so far.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want the absolute val of $p_j - p_j' $.
Two ways
Use a constraint like
$ p_j - p_j' \le \delta_{j,j'}$
where $0 \le \delta_{j,j'} \le U$ is a variable bounded by some upper bound of the difference you think possible.
Then use $\delta$ in place of $ p_j - p_j'$ in the objective or other constraints requiring absolute val.

Another
$ p_j - p_j' = \mu_{j,j'}^+ -\mu_{j,j'}^- $
where $ 0 \le \mu_{j,j'}^+, \mu_{j,j'}^- $
Then use $ \mu_{j,j'}^+ + \mu_{j,j'}^-$ in place of $ p_j - p_j'$ in other relations/expressions